# P tag Text and Border height hovering not working

Tags: html, css

Why are P tag text and Border height increase not working when it is Mouse hovered ? what is the main cause ?

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="cheap">
        <p id= "pen">hello hannan .hello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannanhello hannan</p>

    </div>

</body>

CSS: 

.cheap {
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(25%,55%,45%);
    height: 10px;
}
 p{

 display: none;

}

.cheap:hover {
    width:400px;
    height:500px;

}

p:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/najmul/JwKgG/

Comment: Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/JwKgG/3/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS will work. In your default CSS, your P element is hidden by `display:none` so you have to apply hover to `.cheap` class

```
.cheap {
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(25%,55%,45%);
    height: 10px;
}
.cheap p{
 display: none;
}

.cheap:hover {
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
}

.cheap:hover p {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. Just try this:

```
.cheap:hover p{
display:block;
}
```

add it at the last of your css file.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JwKgG/7/)

Think about that: if the paragraph is displayed none, how can you hover it?